# Liferay translation depending on URL

Tags: url-rewriting, internationalization, liferay, translation

Our website (http://172.x.x.x:8080/web/compagny-name/home) has an English and French versions. By default, the En version is applied and a "Fr" link in the website lets you switch to the French one (http://172.x.x.x:8080/fr/web/compagny-name/home).
We created 2 domain names: www.mywebsite.com and www.mywebsitefr.com. Both are mapped to the same IP:port(172.x.x.x:8080). The problem is the Fr domain name (www.mywebsitefr.com) brings you to the default version (English) and you have to click on the "Fr" link to reach the French one.
I wanted www.mywebsitefr.com brings you directly to http://172.x.x.x:8080/fr/web/compagny-name/home and www.mywebsite.com on http://172.x.x.x:8080/web/compagny-name/home.
I have no idea how to do that and what/where should I search for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to have served to the end user. You could easily have a redirect from `www.mywebsitefr.com` to `www.mywebsite.com/fr/` and just use `www.mywebsite.com` for all content. Especially if it's the same for both languages, just translated. This would leave one site visible to search crawlers (which is nicer than having duplicated content) and you'll have to maintain only one public site.

In terms of Apache, given that mod_rewrite is active, this would be

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mywebsitefr.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.mywebsite.com/fr [R]
  .... other options ....
</VirtualHost>
```

for your french website. The other domain's VirtualHost definition would contain all the proxy-forwarding to Liferay, while this doesn't contain anything.